# How to deal with forced orientation changes if app shouldn't orient?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I have the following problem on an Android 4.4.2 device, the Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini.

If I take a photo with the back-camera, my app kind of restarts and is in an inconsistent state. My main activity is recreated.
I tracked the problem and it seems that this strange behavior happens because the camera app rotates my app. 
This is strange because I setup my app to work only in portrait mode. No O
orientation change is though considered.

Android correctly recognizes this misbehavior and rotates my app back, but exactly that's the problem. On orientation change the activity is recreated and my fragments state is lost.

I don't get this behavior on other phones and also when making a photo with the front camera on the S4 mini.

In my opinion that's a bug either in the android version or in the camera app.

See the following log for details:

Selfie Camera (OK):

- Main activity onCreate
- Fragment onCreate
- User takes a photo and confirms it
- onActivityResult called

Back Camera(NOT OK):

- Main activity onCreate
- Fragment onCreate
- User takes a photo and confirms it
- Fragment onCreate
- Main activity onCreate (app rotated)
- onActivityResult called
- Fragment onCreate
- Main activity onCreate (app rotated correctly back on portrait)

How can I deal with this situation?
Is there a way to stop the camera app doing this.
Or is this a known issue and a workaround exists?

Comment: I create the chooser like this:  
  
`// Photo Choose  
Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);  
Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);  
Intent[] intentArray = {camera};  

Intent chooser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);  
// Gallery Choose  
chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, gallery);  
chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);  
startActivityForResult(chooser, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use surface view [SurfaceView Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) which opens a camera inside the activity instead of using the camera application.

Comment: Could you please provide an example.

Comment: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/surfaceview/android-surfaceview-example/

Comment: @McOzD please accept the answer if it worked for you

Comment: I think this will circumvent the problem but not solve it.
I have to use the pre-installed camera application.